# Count over columns in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a data set in SAS containing individuals as rows and a variable for each period as columns. It looks something like this:

```
data have;
input individual t1 t2 t3;
cards;
1 112 111 123
2 112 111 123
3 111 111 123
4 112 112 111
;
run;
```

What I want is for SAS to count how many there is of each number for each time period. So I want to get something like it:

```
data want;
input count t1 t2 t3;
cards;
111 1 3 1
112 3 1 0
123 0 0 3
;
run;
```

I could do this with proc freq, but outputting this doesn't work very well, when I have a lot of columns.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general having data in the meta data is a bad idea, as here where PERIOD is coded into the Tn variables and you really want that to be a group.  Having said that you can still have your cake and eat it too.

PROC SUMMARY can get the counts for each Tn quickly and then you will have smaller data set to fiddle with.  Here is one approach that should work well for many time periods.

```
data have;
   input individual t1 t2 t3;
   cards;
1 112 111 123
2 112 111 123
3 111 111 123
4 112 112 111
;;;;
run;
proc print;
   run;
proc summary data=have chartype;
   class t:;
   ways 1;
   output out=want;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data want;
   set want;
   p = findc(_type_,'1');
   c = coalesce(of t1-t3);
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc summary data=want nway completetypes;
   class c p;
   freq _freq_;
   output out=final;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
proc transpose data=final out=morefinal(drop=_name_) prefix=t;
   by c;
   id p;
   var _freq_;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]

Comment: \_TYPE_ and \_FREQ_ are getting converted into italic indicators by SO. Add \ in front.

Comment: "In general having data in the meta data is a bad idea".  Why?

Comment: Because it makes it harder to use as in this example where time period and value (111 112) both occupy the same space.  If time period were a variable then it could be used directly in a class.  Which I ended up doing in the second PROC SUMMARY.

Answer (score 1):

First restructure the data so that it is in more of a vertical fashion.  This will be easier to work with.  We also want to create a flag that we will use as a counter later on.

```
data have2;
  set have;
  array arr[*] t1-t3;

  flag = 1;
  do period=lbound(arr) to hbound(arr);    
    val = arr[period];
    output;
  end;

  keep period val flag;
run;
```

Summarize the data so we have the number of times that value occurred in each of the periods.

```
proc sql noprint;
  create table smry as
  select val,
         period,
         sum(flag) as count
  from have3
  group by 1,2
  order by 1,2
  ;
quit;
```

Transpose the data so we have one line per value and then the counts for each period after that:

```
proc transpose data=smry out=want(drop=_name_);
  by val;
  id period;
  var count;
run;
```

Note that when you define the array in the first step you could use this notation which would allow for a dynamic number of periods:

```
  array arr[*] t:;
```

This assumes every variable beginning with 't' in the dataset should go into the array.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer memory is large enough to hold the entire output, then Hash could be a viable solution:

```
data have;
    input individual t1 t2 t3;
    cards;
1 112 111 123
2 112 111 123
3 111 111 123
4 112 112 111
;
run;

data _null_;
    if _n_=1 then
        do;
            /*This is to construct a Hash, where count is tracked and t1-t3 is maintained*/
            declare hash h(ordered:'a');
            h.definekey('count');
            h.definedata('count', 't1','t2','t3');
            h.definedone();
            call missing(count, t1,t2,t3);
        end;

    set have(rename=(t1-t3=_t1-_t3)) 
        /*rename to avoid conflict between input data and Hash object*/
    end=last;

    array _t(*) _t:;
    array t(*) t:;

    /*The key is to set up two arrays, one is for input data, 
    another is for Hash feed,  and maneuver their index variable accordingly*/
    do i=1 to dim(_t);
        count=_t(i);
        rc=h.find(); /*search the Hash and bring back data elements if found*/

        /*If there is a match, then corresponding 't' will increase by '1'*/
        if rc=0 then
            t(i)+1;
        else
            do;
                /*If there is no match, then corresponding 't' will be initialized as '1', 
                                    and all of the other 't' reset to '0'*/
                do j=1 to dim(t);
                    t(j)=0;
                end;

                t(i)=1;
            end;

        rc=h.replace(); /*Update the Hash*/
    end;

    if last then
        rc=h.output(dataset:'want');
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
%macro freq(dsn);
proc sql;
select name into:name separated by ' ' from dictionary.columns where libname='WORK' and memname='HAVE' and name like 't%';
quit;
%let ncol=%sysfunc(countw(&name,%str( )));
%do i=1 %to &ncol;
%let col=%scan(&name,&i);
proc freq data=have;
table &col/out=col_&i(keep=&col count rename=(&col=count count=&col));
run;
%end;
data temp;
    merge
    %do i=1 %to &ncol;
      col_&i
    %end;
 ;
by count;
run;
data want;
   set temp;
   array vars t:;
   do over vars;
     if missing(vars) then vars=0;
   end;
run;
%mend;

%freq(have)
```